# Flexslider slider not autoplaying on WP site despite `slideshow:true`

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

The basics:

- I'm using the BlogMagic theme on WP 4.0
- The slider used is flexslider
- Autoplay is set (`slideshow:true`) in 'jquery.flexslider.js'; I've checked `slideshowSpeed` too and I should be good.
- The slider works fine when using the arrows to navigate between slides (but doesn't autoplay after clicking an arrow either)

So I'm wondering if something is overriding this somewhere? There's a pile of JS files loaded after Flexslider :

- jquery.jplayer.min.js
- jquery.fancybox.pack.js
- spin.min.js
- jquery.isotope.min.js
- jquery.countdown.min.js
- scroll-button.js
- modernizr.custom.js
- jquery.tooltipster.min.js

but I can't see anything in there that would override Flexslider.

There's a final `<script>` tag after all the other linked files too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

        request = true;

        b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
        b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
    }());
</script>
```

Is something missing, is this something really obvious? I'm confused because the slider autoplayed just fine a week or so ago (and I've no way of pinning down exactly what's been changed on the site unfortunately..)

Apologies for the stupid question, and please let me know if I need to add any further info. Oh, and obviously I've had a look through all the settings for the WP theme and that; there's no settings for the slider beyond the basic 'how many featured posts' counter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to say. Url? Do you know if the version of jQuery you're using has changed (are you pointing to a url like /latest for it?)

Comment: I know this is completely useless to solving your current problem but drink the version control kool-aid. You should never have to say "(and I've no way of pinning down exactly what's been changed on the site unfortunately..)".

Comment: @Will I'd usually use git, but I didn't think it was worth it for a couple of small mostly-doable-from-admin-panel modifications! Lesson learnt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a pretty old version of Flexsider. You're [loading 1.8](http://career-center.praditus.com/wp-content/themes/blogmagic/script/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=4.0) and the latest version at [github is 2.3](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider).

I had quite a lot of problems with touch events and desktop browsers with v2.2 so be sure you try any new version on a dev server. Currently, your slider doesn't work at all in Firefox 32 Mac (manually toggling doesn't work either). That's almost certainly related to the onTouchStart callback [referenced in this github ticket](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/958).

Finally, it looks like you have `slideshow: false` on line 115 in http://career-center.praditus.com/wp-content/themes/blogmagic/script/call-scripts.js?ver=4.0

```
// FLEXSLIDER
jQuery('#flexslider').flexslider({slideshow: false});
```

I don't think any of your other JS is conflicting with Flexslider but it does look like there's a lot of superfluous JS being loaded on to the page.

Comment: (Sorry @Will, just realised I never marked your answer as the solution - it solved my problem, thanks!)

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped (and thanks for coming back to it!)